# why is my ub list disappearing. AGAIN

Tags: css

ok guys, u solved this so fast last time. i've altered my sub lists to display horizontally, but when i move off the parent `<li>`, my sub list disappears.

http://www.mymediaventure.com/galleries.php. this happens on the Pricing and the Galleries tab.

Last time it was a z-index issue with the `<h1>` being a higher value than the sub list, but that's not the case anymore. thanks.

Comment: For anyone wondering: Here is the original thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648465/css-dropdown-menu-disappears-when-mouse-moves-off-of-li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you why it's not working. It's because the display of the sub-list only occurs when the cursor hovers over the anchor element in the tab (i.e., Pricing and Galleries). I seen this feature on a bunch of web-sites so I know it can be done.  If you know of one, you might try using Firebug on Firefox to see how it was done.

Here's [a site](http://www.onthefly.com/) using pop-ups although it's table based.

.

After our discussions, I think I have the fix. In following css element, I changed the height from 25px to 30px.

```
#primary_navigation ul#menu li#active a.r span.l span {
background:url("../images/tab_body.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
height:30px;
padding-top:5px;
}
```

I tried 26-29 and they didn't work. The larger height is extending the hover area 5 pixels downwards so it's in contact with the sub-menu.  When it didn't, you left the hover area before entering the sub-menu.

Comment: as i said, i had this problem the other day, (see other thread). and it's attached to the list item, not the anchor. so moving onto the sub unordered list should still mean im within the list item.

Comment: I responded before you added the link. I take it that it used to work. When I move the cursor into 'Galleries' using Firebug, the sub-menu displays when the cursor enters: <a class="r" href="galleries.php">.  It's not fix, just an observation.

Comment: I got the sub-menu to stick by changing the last element in the css to '#primary_navigation ul#menu li.drop:hover'.  The bad news is that is broke the tab activation.  I did the change in Firebug. It might work correctly if you changed the real CSS.

Comment: Just tool another look.  You have the same sub-menu for both 'Pricing' and 'Galleries' so it may be fine.

Comment: sorry mate, i haven't been back for a few days. thanks for the effort, i can't quite seem to see where you mean? could you clear it up for me? which CSS did you change?

Comment: The element is: #primary_navigation ul#menu li.drop:hover ul.sub_sections li a:hover {
color:#F17F17;
}
The site works now. I don't know if it's because I still have the change I made in Firebug.  At any rate, I dropped the last two specifiers as shown in my earlier comment. It appear as the last line in Firebug, but may not be in the actual file.

Comment: yea it is the last line but ive just tested it in firebug (not used to editing css in there) and it didn't work. do i simply edit the selector and hit enter? if that's how then im doing something else wrong :-S

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. I'm not sure why it did the first time. The css seems to be working correctly as written. As soon as you stop hovering over the section causing the display of the sub-menu it stops displaying.  Firebug doesn't save changes across visits to a site so it was working when I made my last replay as is. Firebug generates an error, which is new, but I don't think it has anything to do with the problem.  I'll take another look later.

Comment: Updated the answer in case you're not looking there.

Comment: this looks as if it will work, but will report back later! appreciate it